# Any merit to MSSQLSERVER Trace from logman as opposed to XEvent Package 0

Tags: extended-events, perfmon, trace

The general understanding of monitoring SQL Server activity is that using SQL Profiler is very heavy, server side traces are less heavy, but extended events are even less heavy.

Today I discovered you can capture SQL traces with logman.exe

```
logman query providers
...
MSSQLSERVER Trace                        {17531BCD-C627-46A2-9F1E-7CC920E0E94A}
...
XEvent Package 0                         {60AA9FBF-673B-4553-B7ED-71DCA7F5E972}
...
```

Assuming I'm running SQL Server 2008 or later, is there any reason to ever prefer a tracing session as opposed to extended events here? Does doing tracing through logman eliminate any of the performance issues of a traditional server side trace, or am I still just running a server side trace and just writing the results to an etl file with logman?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at Jonathan's post here: [An XEvent a Day (10 of 31) – Targets Week – etw_classic_sync_target](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/an-xevent-a-day-10-of-31-targets-week-etw_classic_sync_target/)

The provider you see in `logman` is for using the Event Tracing for Windows. I have never used it but from what I understand it is more for tracking events from your application or the Windows OS back into SQL Server. I do not think it is something that can be used to just track general performance of SQL Server like you would with an XEvent session you create in SQL Server.